# Выбор трёх игроков

Tags: java

Имеется `List` с Gamer'ами, мне нужно как-то выбрать из них трёх Gamer'ов с наибольшим кол-вом убийств и наибольшим кол-вом смертей, как такое реализовать?

Сам класс `Gamer` имеет три поля - `name`, `kills` и `deaths`.

Comment: А если игрок лидер по убийствам и ни разу не умирал?

Comment: Я подумал, я решил (kills + deaths) : 2, т.е получится одно число и так сортировать.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Отсортируйте ваш список

```
Collections.sort(gamers, new Comparator<Gamer>(){
   public int compare(Gamer g1, Gamer g2){
      return g2.getKills() + g2.getDeaths() - g1.getKills() -g1.getDeaths();
   }
});
```

И возьмите первые три элемента

```
gamers.subList(0, 3)
```

Comment: А если мне ещё нужно учитывать смерти, то как?

Comment: в методе compare() доопределите влияние.

Comment: @DimXenon +1. Если нужно ещё и смерти - то обозначьте это в вопросе, как именно

Comment: @Chubatiy, обозначил.

Comment: А можете объяснить как метод compare работает?

Comment: http://echuprina.blogspot.com/2012/02/comparable-comparator.html